# Algebra generated by countable union of $\sigma$-algebras of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

im trying to find a **counter example** that shows that $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n})$ where $(X_{n})$ is a sequence of random variables, **is a an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra.**

I havent been able to prove that is not a $\sigma$-algebra, thats why I want to try with a counter example, but I havent found one :/

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the indicator function of the set $\{n\}$.  Then $\sigma(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\left\{\{1\},, \dots, \{n\}\right\}$.  Can you find singletons in $\cup_{n \geq 1} \sigma(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ whose union is not in $\cup_{n \geq 1} \sigma(X_1, \dots, X_n)$?

Comment: The power set of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is not a sigma algebra on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @amsmath  Thanks! Edited.